# accessing menu from multiple threads c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a menu item on my main menu called "Active Reports". when the user selects a report to print, i fire the crystal reports viewer off in a  separate thread. The user could have multiple report viewers open and i want to track them. Mainly this menu list will allow the user to click on the reports and if the report is running too long while it is processing the data for the report, i can fire off an interrupt on that thread to cancel the running report. As each report viewer is closed down, i will remove it from menu list. I have a class called ReportThreadClass which tracks each report that is currently running and the thread it belongs to. After i fire the report off in the thread, i want to update the "Active Reports" menu item and add the name of the report being run to the list of Active Reports. Here is my code for creating the thread and the ReportThreadClass.

```
public class ReportThreadClass
{
    public Thread Thread { get; set; }
    public bool AbortFlag { get; set; }
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
}

  public void RunReport(UAReport report)
    {
        Thread staThread = new Thread(r => ReportDocumentThread((UAReport) r));
        staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
        staThread.Start(report);
    }

    public void ReportDocumentThread(UAReport report)
    {
        var service = new UAReportService(report); //class that creates the report document that will be passed to the report viewer.
        ReportDocument reportDocument = service.CreateReportDocument();
        string reportDesc = report.ReportDesc;

        object args = new object[2] {reportDocument, reportDesc};

        var staThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ReportViewerThread));

        int nextReportId;
        if (!Program.MainForm.ReportThreads.Any())
            nextReportId = 0;
        else
        {
            nextReportId = Program.MainForm.ReportThreads.Count() + 1;
        }

        ReportThreadClass reportThread = new ReportThreadClass();
        reportThread.Thread = staThread;
        reportThread.ReportName = reportDesc;
        reportThread.AbortFlag = false;
        reportThread.ReportId = nextReportId;

        Program.MainForm.ReportThreads.Add(reportThread); //list of all active reports running.
        Program.MainForm.BuildActiveReportsMenu(); //how do i do this from thread.

        staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        staThread.Start(args);
        staThread.Join(100);

    }

    public void ReportViewerThread(object args)
    {
        Array argArray = new object[3];
        argArray = (Array) args;
        ReportDocument reportDocument = (ReportDocument) argArray.GetValue(0);
        string reportDesc = (string) argArray.GetValue(1);

          try
            {
                ReportViewerForm form = new ReportViewerForm(reportDocument, reportDesc);
                form.BringToFront();
                form.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

    }
```

So how can i build the "Active Reports Menu" after i fire off a new report in a thread. Basically i will loop through the ReportThreads list and add the active reports to the "Active Reports" menu item. The ReportThreads list is declared and maintained in the main window. i can access it through Program.MainWindow.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to alter your Form from another thread. To do this, you can use the Invoke method, like this:

```
Program.MainForm.Invoke(() => Program.MainForm.BuildActiveReportsMenu());
```

Comment: what is `Program.MainForm` ?

Comment: The way OP accesses his form. Probably a field or property, I took it directly from his code.

Comment: this is just a hook to the main window for accessing the status bar, menu and toolbar. ok i added this line of code in my code and how do the create the delegate in the main window class.

Comment: The same problem resides in Windows Presentation Foundation - WPF. Whenever you start doing things other threads and try to update the GUI, you get a cross-threading violation. All work on the GUI must be done in the "GUI Thread". How this is fixed in WPF is using Application.Current.Dispatcher or Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher and do provide code wrapped in an action that is able to access the controls and components of GUI.
So the code in this answer uses WinForms technique, but the same problem resides in other frameworks. You cannot access GUI components from other thread than the UI thread.

Comment: >how do the create the delegate in the main window class. public delegate void ??????      What exactly are you talking about?